# Minimal polynomial in splitting field completion

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, minimal-polynomials

Let $K(\theta)/K$ be a field extension with a minimal polynomial $f(X)$ that decompose to $f_1(X) \dots f_g(X)$ in the completion field $K_\mathfrak{p}$ for  some prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$.

I Know that there are exactly $\mathfrak{P}_1, \dots ,\mathfrak{P}_g$ extentions of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $K(\theta)$ and their decomposition groups fulfills:

$
D(\mathfrak{P}_i / \mathfrak{p}) \cong 
Gal(L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_\mathfrak{p}) \cong
Gal(K_p[X]/(f_i(X))) 
$

My question is:

For a splitting field $L/K$ of some polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$
and $\mathfrak{P}_L/\mathfrak{p}_K$ primes, is there any relation between 
the minimal polynomial of the extension $L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_\mathfrak{p}$ and $f(X)$ ?

Also, is it true to say that
$
D(\mathfrak{P} / \mathfrak{p}) \cong 
Gal(L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_\mathfrak{p}) \cong
Gal(K_p[X]/(f(X))) 
$ in this case?

Comment: First case : $f$ is the minimal polynomial of a primitive element then $L_{\mathfrak{P}_i} = K_\mathfrak{p}[X]/(f_i(X))$, one prime/valuation above $\mathfrak{p}$ for each irreducible factor of $f \in K_\mathfrak{p}[X]$. Second case : $L$ is $F \in K[X]$'s splitting field then $L_{\mathfrak{P}_i} $ is $F \in K_\mathfrak{p}[X]$'s splitting field, all the primes are in the same Galois orbit and $Gal(L_{\mathfrak{P}_i}/K_\mathfrak{p}) = Gal(F \in K_\mathfrak{p}[X])$ what changes with $i$ is the way to embed $Gal(F \in K_\mathfrak{p}[X])$ into $Gal(F \in K[X])$

Comment: Can you give me some proof for the second case?

Comment: Is $K$ a field? If so, what does a prime of $K$ mean? If not, what do you mean by field extension?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen The OP probably meant a number field, thus $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of $O_K$, more generally $K$ is any field and $\mathfrak{p}$  is a discrete valuation on $K$ (inducing an absolute value for which we can take the completion).

Comment: @reuns can you give some proof?

Comment: It is obvious from the definition of the completion.